# javascript compare strings case sensative

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I want to implement a case sensitive comparison between 2 string.
Here's what I have done so far, it is not working so well

```
function compare(x,y){
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++){
  var xc = x[i];
  var yc = y[i];
  if (xc == yc) 
     continue;
  var xclow = x.toLowerCase();
  var yclow = y.toLowerCase();
    if (xclow == yclow)
        return xc < yc ? -1 : 1
    else
        return xclow  < yclow ? -1 : 1;

}
```

}

if im doing `console.log(compare("Kk","kk"));` I'm getting -1 as expected,but if i'm doing `console.log(compare("Kka","kk"));`i'm getting 1 and i don't know why.

Comment: Compression? Comparison?

Comment: WTH are you doing `toLowerCase` if you want it to be case *sensitive*?

Comment: Comparison of course ,sorry a misspell

Comment: "*`return x.length.localeCompare(y.length);`*" is dead code. Remove it.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, will do

Comment: @Bergi ,because it easier, and I'm also checking the upper case in case of equation

Comment: "*because it's easier*" - I don't see that. When would the lower case comparison ever yield a different result than the simple direct `return xc < yc ? -1 : 1` comparison?

Comment: Btw, you are also lacking a `return x.length - y.length` statement after the loop (i.e. when all the iterated characters were equal)

Comment: @Bergi, ok i now checked, i cahnged to to `return xc < yc ? -1 : 1` and on `console.log(compare("kk","kk"));` im getting undefined instead of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was two typo, you had written `x.toLowerCase();` instead of `xc.toLowerCase();` and `y.toLowerCase();` instead of `yc.toLowerCase();`

```
function compare(x, y) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++) {
        var xc = x[i];
        var yc = y[i];
        if (xc == yc)
            continue;
        var xclow = xc.toLowerCase();
        var yclow = yc.toLowerCase();
        if (xclow == yclow)
            return xc < yc ? -1 : 1
        else
            return xclow < yclow ? -1 : 1;
        return x.length.localeCompare(y.length);
    }
}
```

By the way, last return statement is unnecessary since both if and else contains return statement.

> There are more simpler ways to do that but I think you're trying to accomplish that on your own.

Comment: Thanks, but still the return value is still incorrect

Comment: @styx: `compare("Kka","kk")` yields `-1` as expected now. What's wrong?

Comment: @Bergi, for some reason i didn't worked for, now works fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not use just `"Kk" === "kk"`?

```
function compare(x, y) {
    return x === y;
    // or return x === y ? 1 : -1
}
```

Comment: your answer is right , dont know who downvoted you though

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want to test for equality, but rather write a [comparison function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Something like:

```
 console.log('a'.localeCompare('A', { sensitivity: 'variant' }));
```

You can add the locale if you need etc.